# Laravel 4.2 Typecasting Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Why would dd( Auth::id() ) return an integer on one server but a string on another server?

dd(Auth::id());

int(68) // local server

string(2) "68" // staging server

Comment: Are they sharing a database, using different databases but the same type or different database systems?

Comment: Are the columns in your databases from the same type?

Comment: The staging database is an exact clone and being imported from a SQL dump of the local server